# Strapi nested, return error Knex: Timeout acquiring a connection. The pool is probably full. Are you missing a .transacting(trx) call

Tags: graphql, strapi

I have this query :

```
 query{
    employees{
      fullname
      department
      position
      presences(where:{created_at_gt:"20200401"}){
        created_at
        Status
      }
    }
}
```

it return error :

```
errors": [
    {
      "message": "Knex: Timeout acquiring a connection. The pool is probably full. Are you missing a .transacting(trx) call?",
...
```

but when I change query to :

```
 query{
        presences(where:{created_at_gt:"20200401"}){
      created_at
      Status
        employee{
        fullname
        department
        position
      }
    }
}
```

it's work

it's seem the strapi cannot filter the presences

Comment: How are you managing connections?

Answer (score 0):

In the first instance you are passing args to `presences` as a field on employee, and thus any filtering would be handled on the sub-resolver level (not top level query). You should confirm you are appropriately handling the subresolver and its passed args.

By contrast, in the second example, you are accessing presences as a top level Query -- in other words, a graph entry point, where I anticipate you are properly handling the filtering condition.

And FWIW, with knex, I have had success managing connections using the following pattern, similar to what's outlined in the docs somewhere:

```
const trxProvider = knex.transactionProvider();

firstTrx = await trxProvider(); 
   // Use firstTrx
   // **Some other logic***
secondTrx = await trxProvider();
   // Use secondTrx
   // **Some other logic***
thirdTrx = await trxProvider();
      // Use thirdTrx then commit
      thirdTrx.commit();
```

You can create these transaction references conveniently at will, and they will all refer to the same trx (even though labeled with different names). This is particularly helpful if you trx is being passed to a callback(s), but you would like to finally commit, for example, from the initially invoking function. Following this pattern helped greatly with our connection issues.

Finally, if none else works, you can attempt modifying your connection manager config (see pool below):

```
 {
    client: 'pg',
    connection: {
      host: 
      port:
      user: 
      database: 
      password: 
    },
    pool: { min: 2, max: 20 },
    asyncStackTraces: true
  };
}
```

Comment: if I want to query all presence with date range for each employee, how is the best query using graphql, if it's require custom service, how to achieve this